# XSLT and Xpath Issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

XML:

```
    <root>
<events>
    <event id="e1" v_id="v1">
        <elements></elements>
    </event>
    <event id="e1" v_id="v2">
        <elements></elements>
    </event>
    <event id="e1" v_id="v2">
        <elements></elements>
    </event>
</events>

<venues>
    <venue venue_id="v1">
        <venue_name></venue_name>
        <elements></elements>
    </venue>
    <venue venue_id="v2">
        <venue_name></venue_name>
        <elements></elements>
    </venue>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/events/event"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="event">
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/venues/venue[@venue_id = /root/events/event/@v_id]/venue_name"/>
        <xsl:text>This is where I would like to put the venue name as a link to that venue</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
```

so if the v_id = v2 and the venue_id = v2 I want to display the value of venue_name from the venue with id = v2

Thanks

Comment: why there are different opening and closing tags in your xml?<element1 v_id="v1" e_id="e4">
<some_elements_here></some_elements_here>
<some_elements_here></some_elements_here>
</element>

Comment: XML: 
Root
Child1
Child1.1
Child1.2
Child2
Child2.1
2.1Name <value>
Child2.2

Comment: `venue_name` is empty everywhere -- why the fuss at all? Please, edit your question and provide meaningful data. Don't expect the answerer to do your work for you! -1.

Comment: Yea I know it is empty I am not asking for help with content it is an issuue with the xpath. How can I compare two attributes from one template about venue that compares the attribute from events

Comment: @Delta_Cmdr How do you expect someone who has no idea about your content to help you, if you don't explicitly show it to him?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of issue that keys are designed to deal with.

In the root of your stylesheet, add

```
<xsl:key name="venue" match="venue" use="@venue_id" />
```

This effectively declares an associative array of all `venue` elements, indexed on their `venue_id` attribute. With this, you can get the `venue` element with any given `venue_id` attribute using the `key` function. I believe you can achieve what you need by substituting your `<xsl:text>` line with this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('venue', @v_id)/venue_name" />
```

This essentially looks up the right `venue` element, and gets the `venue_name` child within it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to the whole forum thing and I apologize if my question was a bit vague. Again thank you it works perfectly!

Comment: Don't worry, there was nothing vague about it. I still can't understand why some people can't see that the content of the `venue_name` elements is entirely irrelevant to the solution, it seemed pretty clear to me.